# CSRF protection when making web apps using AJAX and no inline php

Tags: javascript, ajax

Just starting to get my head around rebuilding an app so all php is
accessed via AJAX ie no inline php, in preparation for making it a
native app using Phonegap.

One thing I'm wondering - currently (as the site is now with inline php)
I use random string generation to determine if the call is coming from
my site (this is to help avoid CSRF, right)?

ie...

- create rand str
- chuck it in session
- send it with any AJAX calls, and check it matches the one in session

How is this possible when you're not using inline php? Do I have to...

- from the first AJAX call, create a rand str in php during the call,
  and return it
- store the str in a js var
- send it back in the next AJAX
- check it matches the one in session, and if so all is good
- create a fresh rand str, and send it back to AJAX, ready for the next
  AJAX call

?

if the above is correct, how do you know the very first AJAX call hasn't been hacked?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"hacked"*?

Comment: I'm a rookie when it comes to this stuff, but from what I understand, doing random string checks in session from each form call proves that the call is coming from the user's computer, and not the computer of someone else who has hijacked this session. Is this incorrect? So I'm wondering, how do you know they haven't hijacked the session from the beginning?

Comment: CSRF is about ensuring that submitted data comes from the last form (typically) presented in the session and that submissions cannot be replayed. You fetch the token before showing the form and then make sure that token is part of any submission. You can't tell any more than that. I suggest you read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: Ahh - so it's ok to generate the initial token in javascript, send it to the server in the first AJAX request, and save it in session for comparing with subsequent requests until the session ends. I was thinking the token had to be generated server side first up.

Comment: No, never generate the token client-side. Always generate it server-side and replace it with a new one with each submission

Comment: Thanks Phil. But that's where I'm confused when dealing with web-apps that have no inline php. I understand with inline php you can render a form or javascript var to contain an echoed token from serverside. But with no inline php, the first interaction with your server comes from ajax. Sure - after that first interaction, you can return a server side token, but that first interaction doesn't have a token.

Comment: Why shouldn't that first interaction return a CSRF token? Why not have a PHP service that generates and returns tokens (per form ID or something)? Then you just hit the service and grab the next token to use in data submissions. You could do it on page load or hook in to a form's submit event.

Comment: But what I mean is - doesn't the first AJAX interaction ALSO have to send a token from javascript to php? You can do this if using inline php by echoing the php token to a js var to send with AJAX, but if your only connection with php is AJAX (ie no inline php echoing to build the html), then you can't initially populate that js var. Or doesn't it matter on the first interaction?